# Scroll in deep nested flexible containers

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, flexbox

In this code example i have implemented flexible scroll container, in deep flexible nesting structure.

https://jsfiddle.net/n3vctjr4/

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.static {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: red;
}

.flexible {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.flexible div {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.overflow {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Container element -->
<div class="container">

 <!-- Not flexible container -->
  <div class="static">HEADER</div>

  <!-- Flexible container -->
  <div class="flexible">
    
    <!-- Nested containers -->
    <div class="nesting-1">
      <div class="nesting-2">
        <div class="nesting-3">
          <div class="nesting-4">
            <div class="nesting-5">
              
              <!-- Scrollable container -->
              <div class="nesting-6 overflow">
                <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
                scroll here
                <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
                <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
                end
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Not flexible container -->
  <div class="static">FOOTER</div>
  
</div>
```

Is there any other, better/simpler solution other than putting min-height and display:flex on each div in the "flexible" hierarchy all the way to the top element?

Answer (score 0):

We can get rid off  `display: flex`, as there is no horizontally aligned elements. So our task is just  to create vertically aligned elements. We know that `div` has by default `display: block`, so let's use it:

```css
*, html, body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.static {
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 10%;
  background: red;
}

.middle {
  height: 80%;
}

.overflow {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="static">HEADER</div>
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="nesting-1">
        <div class="nesting-2">
          <div class="nesting-3">
            <div class="nesting-4">
              <div class="nesting-5">
                <div class="nesting-6 overflow">
                  <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
                  scroll here
                  <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
                  <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
                  end
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="static">FOOTER</div>
  </div>
```